# Is a 500 watt floodlight compatable with Raspberry Pi Relay Board v1.0?

Tags: relay

A have Raspberry Pi Relay Board v1.0 — http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Relay_Board_v1.0

And I also have a 500 watt floodlight (here is the picture of the box — https://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/PMxgs9BN5t9F1xyl6vw4cn1jAy0.jpg )

I'm living in the county where there is 220 vols in the electical network (in case it matters).

It is ok to connect this floodlight to the this relay board?

There is [a specification for this board](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Relay_Board_v1.0#Specification), `Switching Power Max 2770VA/240 W`, but I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifications for the board state a maximum of 250 volts AC, which covers your 220v reference. The current draw that the board can handle is rated for AC voltage at 15 amperes. Considering the poorer application of 110vac, a 500 watt lamp will draw slightly more than 5 amperes. With 220vac available, if the lamp will so operate, you'd be drawing less than 2.5 amperes, well within the 15 ampere rating of the board.

I would expect no problems connecting the load you've described. Note also the limitations in the specifications for DC power switching. It's much lower and should be observed if you were to use this item in the future for DC devices.

All numbers and math noted above are approximations, as precision is not required due to the latitude of the devices involved.